# How to use the type and why compiler complains infinite type?

Tags: haskell

I have following type:

```
newtype Moi s a =
  Moi { runMoi :: s -> (a, s) }
```

the data constructor expects a function as the argument and it should return a tuple.

I tried following:

```
*OwnState> :t Moi (+1)
```

the compiler complains:

```
<interactive>:1:6: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: s ~ (a, s)
      Expected type: s -> (a, s)
        Actual type: (a, s) -> (a, s)
    * In the first argument of `Moi', namely `(+ 1)'
      In the expression: Moi (+ 1)
```

First look at the type signature of `(+1)`:

```
*OwnState> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a
```

The type `a` has to be constraint to `Num` typeclass.

So when I write `Moi (+1)`, what is going to happen, how the type is going to be substitute?

Let's analyze the error message as the next step:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: s ~ (a, s)
```

Tilde means `~` type equality and how the compiler comes to conclusion that `s` has the same type as `(a, s)`?

I suppose, the type substitution of example above works in this way:

```
n -> n "Type of (+1)
|    |
s -> (a, s)
```

then `s` becomes to `(a, s)` and the proof `s ~ (a, s)` is true.

```
(a, s) -> (a, s)
```

But I can not see, why it is infinite type.

Comment: It is infinite because `s` occurs both on the left and right side of `~` and not in the semantical part. So after one substitution, it is `s ~ (a,s) ~ (a,(a,s))`, etc.

Comment: `s ~ (a,s)` is not true -- unification fails in the "occurs check" step. Indeed, there is no type `T` for which `(a,T)` is still the same type: the second intuitively contains one additional `a`. It is like solving `n=n+1` on numbers: it has no solution, unless you somehow allow "infinity" as a number.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  can you please show for a learner like me, how to substitute a type. I saw a lot of many cases, how substitution works, but not sure, if I am right or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I can not see, why it is infinite type.

Because `s` occurs both at the left and right side of the type equality `~`, and this in a recursive fashion. After one substitution, we have:

```
s ~ (a,s)
```

But note that `s` in `(a,s)` should also be substituted, so:

```
s ~ (a,s) ~ (a,(a,s)) ~ (a,(a,(a,s))) ~ ...
```

So in order to construct this type it would result in a type with infinitely nested 2-tuples. Haskell can not handle such types.

`Moi (+1)` simply does not match the specifications of this "*state monad*". You probably want to use:

```
Moi (\x -> (x,x+1))
```

or:

```
Moi (ap (,) (1 +))
```